# Пороги для получения знаков и прочих плюшек

Tags: обсуждение, знаки

Рассмотрим, к примеру знак *Лучший ответ*: Ответ с рейтингом 100 и более баллов. Аналогичный знак присутствует и на основном [en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer). Вот только зарегистрированных людей на основном SO примерно в 84 раза больше (см. [люди en.SO](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) и [люди ru.SO](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/355/alltime/ru-stackoverflow)). По количеству активных участников соотношение аналогичное. В связи с этим **вопрос**: не рассматривалась ли инициатива на ru.SO предоставлять участникам знаки и еще какие-либо возможности по сниженному по сравнению с en.SO порогу? Ведь кол-во людей, которые могут повлиять на получение того же знака *Лучший ответ* меньше => возможности его получить меньше.

Comment: Сниженный порог...хех. Тут наоборот N-ное время назад некоторые повысили, а то слишком зашиковались :D

Comment: Лучше зовите больше людей в проект)

Comment: А давайте для SO повысим вместо этого? Ну, скажем, 1000 баллов набрать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну такие «некоторые», как Вы выразились, есть и на en.So. Я не про это. Я про то, что несколько некорректно одинаковые стандарты вводить для разных по численности сообществ. Это иногда некорректно работает, а именно, когда получение чего-то зависит от посторонних.

Comment: @Jenssen а какие именно знаки вы считаете надо пересмотреть?  Там разве что знак "Публицист" и "Знаменитый вопрос" трудный. А в целом там никаких занебесных требований нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - Звездный вопрос, Лучший вопрос, Лучший ответ, Популист, Легенда - например, эти. В частности, знак «лучший ответ» на en.SO приходится 1 на примерно 155 человек, а на ru.SO их 6 всего, т.е. 1 знак на каждые 15888 человек. Ощущаете разницу?

Comment: Помимо знаков, я точно не знаю, возможно, есть еще какие-то вещи на сайте, получение которых зависит от кол-ва пользователей.

Comment: @Jenssen так может это ИМ ТАМ надо планку поднять, а не нам  опустить? ;-)

Comment: @Jenssen ну и знаки зарабатываются не за день или два, а за долгое время. Поэтому хотите Лучший ответ заработать - ждите своих заветных честных 100 баллов,  а не вымаливайте снизить порог ;-)

Comment: Если честно, я не очень большой фанат знаков, но если у большого сообщества планка ниже на знаки, то я лучше пойду забугор, там badges пособираю;)

Comment: Ну а смысл этих знаков, если специально нужно для них идти забугор? С точки зрения коллекционера иметь значок, которых всего несколько во всем мире, куда круче, чем иметь значок, который уже несколько миллионов раздали.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня одна тревога уже несколько дней висит, можете проверить ее? А то глаза мозолит. Извиняюсь, что сюда пишу, просто с телефона неудобно. Можете потом удалить этот комментарий.

Comment: [евреймодон]Давайте снизим порог в 42 раза и ценность всё ещё будет в 2 раза круче ихней[/евреймодофф].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На мой взгляд, не нужно ничего занижать, мы же вроде не соревнуемся с en.SO по количеству знаков и badges? В одной работе Senior Developer'ом называют тех кто год проработал, на другой и с опытом 10 лет не каждый сможет стать Senior'ом. Это не большая проблема, особенно если с одной работы в другую народ не переходит.

Да, некоторые badges заработать на ru.SO сложнее, ну и что? По-моему, так только интереснее, к тому же получит значок, которые есть у 3 человек на всем рунете намного приятнее, чем значок, которые получили 300 тысяч.

У меня наоборот на большом SO почти все значки уже есть и уже не так интересно зарабатывать парочку оставшихся. Плюс, снижать лимиты не совсем честно по отношению к тем, кто уже заработал редкие значки.

Вообще, лучше считать en.SO и ru.SO совсем разными ресурсами с разным весом значков, тогда и вопросов не будет. Вы же не можете значок с en.SO конвертировать в значок в ru.SO?

Comment: А в чём разница между знаками и "badges"?